# Why can I not append a line to a file using StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

Why does my program overwrite the same line in the file?

I want it to record a line every time I use the `StreamWriter`.

```
String path = @"c:\Observer\Employer\Employer.txt";
TextWriter write1 = new StreamWriter(path);

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
    TextWriter write2 = new StreamWriter(path);
    write2.WriteLine(Info);
    write2.Close();
}
else if (File.Exists(path))
{
    write1.WriteLine(Info);
    write1.Close();
}

write1.Close();
```

Comment: You need to open the file for appending. You're opening the file and placing the write cursor at the beginning. There's a setting for this somewhere; look it up on MSDN. Also, you should check if the file exists *before* trying to open it with `StreamReader`. Moreover, your 2nd `File.Exists` is redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the overload you're using overwrites the file. Here's what it looks like under the covers:

```
public StreamWriter(String path) 
    : this(path, false, UTF8NoBOM, DefaultBufferSize) {
}
```

The second parameter tells it whether to append (true) or overwrite (false).

You have to explicitly tell it to append text to the file:

```
TextWriter write1 = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

Comment: i use true for the second parameter (for appending) and it works  right thx :D

Answer (score 3):

As @GrantWinney wrote, this is expected behavior. Anyway, instead of the entire code, you may want to use just

```
File.AppendAllText(path, Info)
```

instead. It seems it has all the functionality you need. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need open the file in append mode in order to add lines to it. Use the optional second parameter set to true, like so:

```
TextWriter write1 = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```